# Touch-friendly whiteboard

Tags: windows, whiteboard

I have a touch screen that would make a great smart board, but I haven't been able to find the software to make this happen. There are several websites with great features but browsers don't let webpages handle multi-touch gestures. Here are my requirements in order of importance:

### Requirements

- Free-hand drawing
- Multi-touch support/gestures
- Insert image
- Zoom-able
- Windows/Linux

### Desired

- Allow for multiple drawers
- Easily draw shapes
- Export to image
- Plugin API
- Open source